# Prism WPF MVVM Hello World

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm trying to find a Windows friendly UI development environment that I can translate what experience I do have into something usable, maintainable, and current. I like the idea of a web based UI, but that introduces another problem since a local Windows platform is required to perform various computations (because that's where the binaries and licenses are available).

I've decided on WPF + a well supported MVVM framework like Prism as a starting point. I have looked at the WPF samples they provide here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

For the Prism supplied "examples", there isn't much of a description for what is going on in each step. There is mention of a Hello World example being added 3 years ago, but that doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Does anyone know of a good, simple example, based on the current Prism WPF Template, showing how to implement a "Hello World" type application? In my mind, something where you click a button that fires off an activity that when complete, will update a text box, or any other text/numeric control on the UI?

Comment: If you're new to wpf then I suggest you do not use PRISM. It is very complicated and you will not use 99.9% of what it offers. EG do you need to be able to inject an entirely dynamic UI or are you actually going to have set views?

Comment: @Andy: I'm happy to answer any questions. The main reason PRISM "looked good" was that their WPF Template seemed like it had the least cruft, and would be easiest to understand and build on.

I would like to avoid unnecessary stuff, and that is why MVVM Light seemed appealing, but again, no Hello World example...A Hello World with a custom MVVM template would probably be best

Comment: While Prism is a fun framework to use, it seems to me (based on your question) like you need to get to understand how WPF and MVVM works first, before you can understand Prism. Use some of the widely available WPF tutorials online and get to understand how MVVM projects work. When you get about 3 - 6 months experience in working with that you should be able to understand how things fit together. Also understanding concepts like IOC and SOLID principles will help greatly here as the framework assumes you understand those concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on further explanation in the comments.
PRISM has a huge amount of cruft rather than least and I suggest you instead look at mvvmlight. The way I would usually work is to create a new wpf app then add mvvmlightibs as a package using nuget.

I put together two samples you might find relevant:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

The second uses mvvmlight.

I'm not suggesting you read just my articles but I have a bunch of them on wpf and a lot are aimed at newbies.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30959.user-page-andy-oneill.aspx

Comment: I think this is pretty reasonable as an answer, but would like to leave things open...in the meantime I will review what you posted and come back here with my thoughts.

Comment: This has been quite helpful in reevaluating what I am trying to do, and believe this would be helpful to others.